# Excel VBA compare, add row and fill in

Tags: excel, vba, compare

So this is an example of my data:

A1.   1

A2.  2

A3.  5

A4.  7

A5.  8

A6.  9

A7.  10

What I want to do is select a range (e.g. from A2 to End of the row that has data), insert a row if the next number in the sequence does not equal the previous number + 1. Fill in that number (previous number +1) into the row that was just created then jump to the next row and recompute. This will continue until the program encounters a null value.

This is how I envision it to be in pseudo

```
  Range = select range in column

  For range when value is not null

  If A3 <> value in A2 +1

     Insert row below A2
     Insert value into new A2 (should Now be blank) as sum of A2 + 1
     Then go to next row
     Go back to blank check for loop 
  Else

      Go to next row
      Go back to blank check

  End for
```

I’m not entirely sure if I’ve missed something but I’m terrible at loops in VBA as it’s been many years since I last used it.
Sorry for the formatting, did this on a phone

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic through the code is fairly sound, but if you're planning to program more, it never hurts to practice the actual syntax. I've changed it so that it checks to see if the cell is empty which I'm assuming is what you mean by Null, but if you actually mean a NULL then you can change the `isempty` to `isnull`. I've sort of allowed you to select a range, but not really. It requires you to step in to the code and change the `maxrow` to the last row you wish to look at. Keep in mind, if your code is missing numbers in between, it'll only look up to 100 values including the ones that are placed by the macro.

If you want the user to be able to have the user put in the last row number more easily, consider using an `InputBox`

```
Option Explicit

Sub numberfiller()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim maxrow As Long

    i = 2
    maxrow = 100
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        While Not IsEmpty(.Range("A" & i).Value) And i < maxrow
            If Not .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value + 1 Then
                .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
                .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value + 1
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow I wasn’t expecting something so smooth. Next time I’ll use actual syntax instead of pseudo and try to clarify abit more. Thank you very much, I’ll practice more. The differences between vba and C ruins my day sometimes aha.